# Using any() or all() with is.na() over multiple columns

Tags: r

I'd like to drop rows from my dataset that are all NAs (AKA keep rows with any non-NAs) for a list of columns. How could I update this code so that `x` & `y` are supplied as a vector? This would enable me to flexibly add and drop columns for inspection.

```
library(dplyr)

ds <- 
  tibble(
  id = c(1:4),
    x = c(NA, 1, NA, 4),
    y = c(NA, NA , 3, 4)
  ) 

ds %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(
    any(
      !is.na(x),
      !is.na(y)
    ) 
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I'm trying to write something like `any(!is.na(c(x,y)))` but I'm not sure how to supply multiple arguments to `is.na()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `filter_at` with `any_vars`

```
ds %>% 
   filter_at(vars(x:y), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     id     x     y
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     1    NA
#2     3    NA     3
#3     4     4     4
```

---

-Update - Feb 7 2022

In the new version of `dplyr` (as @GitHunter0 suggested) can use `if_all/if_any` or `across`

```
ds %>%
    filter(if_any(x:y, complete.cases))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id     x     y
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     1    NA
2     3    NA     3
3     4     4     4
```

Comment: The new dplyr API uses `across()` and `if_any()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ds %>% filter(!if_all(x:y, is.na))`.